# Door Replacement: Pre-Hung doors vs Slab doors

Tags: doors, door-frame

A building needs to have its doors replaced: when does it make sense to replace with a slab and when does it make sense to replace with a pre-hung door?

The doors need to be replaced because they are falling apart & no longer close.  The interior and some exterior doors are wood.    The goal is to understand what questions should be asked when determining if a slab or pre-hung door is warranted.

Comment: Do you need new jambs (and trim, and hardware)? There you go.

Comment: My point is that the question is very broad. Maybe explain *why* the doors need replacing, what type of doors they are, and what the building construction is like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I hope that the update provides enough context.  I'd like to understand how to recognize when it makes sense to use a pre-hung door and not a slab

Comment: You don't say what components of the doors are "falling apart". The only question to ask is whether the jambs have structural issues. It's akin to asking whether you should replace the glass in a window or the entire window. Which do you need? If you need help determining that, post photos.

Comment: As stated  **"The doors need to be replaced because they are falling apart & no longer close."** does not tell us anything.  Are they failing because of the jamb?